# Nancy Cartwright's dichotomy

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, mathematical-philosophy

[Nancy Cartwright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Cartwright_(philosopher)) introduced an interesting distinction with regard to modeling of physical phenomena. According to Cartwright, a mathematical theory is not applied directly to such phenomena.  Rather, one first builds a basic mathematical model of the phenomenon in question, in a step Cartwright refers
to as *phenomenological model-building* (I think she uses "phenomenological" in the sense of "empirical" but I may be wrong).  Only then does one exploit a full-fledged mathematical theory, applied not to the original phenomenon but rather to the basic mathematical model.  Since I am not familiar with the relevant literature, I am wondering if this distinction has been explored further in recent work.

The relevant papers are the following:

Cartwright, Nancy; Shomar, Towfic; Su'arez, Mauricio.  The tool box
of science.  Tools for the building of models with a superconductivity
example. Poznan Studies in the Philosophy of the Sciences and the
Humanities 44 (1995), 137--149.

Su'arez, Mauricio; Cartwright, Nancy.  Theories: Tools versus models.
Studies in History and Philosophy of Science Part B: Studies in
History and Philosophy of Modern Physics, Vol. 39, Issue 1 (2008),
62--81.  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.shpsb.2007.05.004.

Comment: I'm not down-voting or voting to close, but to me this line of inquiry seems like a part of the philosophy of science, and not a part of mathematics per se.

Comment: Well it certainly has to do with mathematical modeling in mathematical physics.  We have both a tag for mathematical physics, and a tag for reference request, which is what this question is.

Comment: @SamHopkins, I myself tend to think that mildly philosophical questions about mathematics _can_ be part of mathematics, and needn't be partitioned-off... since mathematicians' attitudes/philosophies about things certainly have an effect on the course of events ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cartwright's case study, model building for the theory of superconductivity, has been explored further in the Ph.D.thesis [The Role of Concrete Models in the Revolution in Superconductivity](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/9818/Chattoraj__Ananya.pdf;sequence=1) (A. Chattoraj, 2015).

More generally, one of Cartwright's former students, Roman Frigg, has developed this approach in a monograph, [Models and theories: A philosophical inquiry](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/handle/20.500.12657/57620/9781000609530.pdf?sequence=1) (2022).

Comment: Is it correct to describe Cartwright's insight as follows?  London and London developed a phenomenological model of superconductivity.  Eventually (two decades later?), what is considered a proper theoretical explanation at the molecular level was developed.  However, Cartwright stresses the importance of the model, and notes that sometimes the significance of models is not sufficiently appreciated when people think of theory as explaining the phenomena directly.  ??

Comment: as a physicist, this distinction between a "model" and a "theory" does not resonate with me; what we seek is an "explanation"; the fact that a superconductor has zero resistance was known since 1911; we had to wait until 1957 for an explanation why (BCS theory); London&London in 1935 described the 1911 observations in terms of mathematical equations, without connecting these equations with established physical foundations; their equations "came out of the blue"; this is why their work is not considered an explanation of superconductivity.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Is it generally thought that the London-London "model" (if you allow me to use that term) was helpful in eventually motivating the BCS theory two decades later?

Comment: P.S. I really know nothing about this, but the point of the London-London 1935 thing seems to have been not to explain zero resistance (known since 1911), but rather to explain zero magnetic field (known only since 1933).  Is this accurate?

Comment: yes, this is accurate (although the two are intimately related: the magnetic field is "expelled" from the superconductor by an electrical current which does not decay because the resistance is zero); the point I wish to make is that the London equation describes the field expulsion by adding "by hand" an equation to the Maxwell equations of electrodynamics, without _explaining_ where this equation comes from; the BCS theory _derives_ the London equation, which is why for a physicist the BCS theory explains superconductivity while the London equation does not.

Comment: Carlo, you wrote: "this distinction between a *model* and a *theory* does not resonate with me; what we seek is an *explanation*."  I don't think this is incompatible with Cartwright's distinction.  Namely, there could be several stages to an explanation.  As you point out, the BCS theory derives the London equation, but the latter could have served as an explanation for the former.  Somebody at a parallel site mentioned that there was a kind of model for Eistein's relativity before the general theory emerged...

Comment: ... Why would looking for an *explanation* be incompatible with the idea that there may be stages in arriving at a satisfactory explanation?